# XyMTeX ChemEquation alignment

Tags: align, chemistry, xymtex

I am trying to figure out how / why structures are aligned in XyMTeX - it's doing my head in.
Why does this code generate this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtexpdf}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% fix the issue with \smash
\def\dotnodimension{\hbox{\smash{\hbox to0pt{\hss.\hss}}}}
%%%

\begin{document}
    \begin{ChemEquation}
        \fbox{
        \begin{XyMcompd}(400,400)(100,100){}{}
            \ltetrahedralS{0==C;1==A;2==B;3A==X;4B==Y}
        \end{XyMcompd}
    }
    \fbox{
        \begin{XyMcompd}(400,400)(100,100){}{}
            \LewistetrahedralA{0==C;1==A;2==B;3A==X;4B==Y}
        \end{XyMcompd}  
    }
        \fbox{
        \begin{XyMcompd}(400,400)(100,100){}{}
            \LewisTetrahedralA{0==C;1==A;2==B;3A==X;4B==Y}
        \end{XyMcompd}  
    }
        \fbox{
        \begin{XyMcompd}(400,400)(100,100){}{}
            \LewistetrahedralA{0==C;1==A;2==B;3A==X;4B==Y}
        \end{XyMcompd}  
    }
        \fbox{
        \begin{XyMcompd}(400,400)(100,100){}{}
            \LewistetrahedralA{0==C;1==A;2==B;3A==X;4B==Y}
        \end{XyMcompd}  
    }
        \fbox{
        \begin{XyMcompd}(400,400)(100,100){}{}
            \rtetrahedralS{0==C;1==A;2==B;3A==X;4B==Y}
        \end{XyMcompd}  
    }
        \fbox{
        \begin{XyMcompd}(400,400)(100,100){}{}
            \rtetrahedralS{0==C;1==A;2==B;3A==X;4B==Y}
        \end{XyMcompd}  
    }
        \end{ChemEquation}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: various Lewis structures]

Comment: Why adding the `XyMcompd` environment?

Comment: I was doing some tests for what the image sizes were. This was just a test for figuring out how it works.